# Big O Notation analysis using recursion tree

Tags: recursion, big-o, complexity-theory, recurrence, divide-and-conquer

A problem from: http://qpleple.com/divide-and-conquer/
Comparison of algorithms

> You are product manager at Facebook and three engineers from your team come up with these three algorithms to detect fake Facebook accounts in the list of n=1 billion Facebook accounts.
>
> Rakesh solves problems by dividing them into five subproblems of half the size, recursively solving each subproblem, and then combining the solutions in linear time.
>
> Chris solves problems of size n by recursively solving two subproblems of size n−1 and then combining the solutions in constant time.
>
> Matus solves problems of size n by dividing them into nine subproblems of size `n/3`, recursively solving each subproblem, and then combining the solutions in `O(n²)` time

So by using the Master Theorem I found out that:

- Rakesh's algorithm has a running time of `O(nlog₂(5))`
- Matus' algorithm has a running time of `O(n2log(n))`

Drawing out a recursive tree and using:
[image: equation]

Rasket's algorithm has:

```
 #levels = log₂(n) 
 #of nodes at level k = 5k
 overhead per node at level k = n/2k
```

But no matter how hard I try, I can't get the summation to equal `O(nlog₂(5))`, and the same goes for Matus's algorithm.

Also, is there a way to solve the running time for Chris' algorithm with the Master Theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying

```
#levels = log₂(n)
#of nodes at level k = 5k
overhead per node at level k = n/2k
```

to [image: Equation]

You get (using the [geometric formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula))

```
T(n) = Σk=0,...,log₂(n) 5k ⋅ n/2k
     = n ⋅ Σk=0,...,log₂(n) (5/2)k
     = n ⋅ (1 - (5/2)log₂(n)+1) / (1 - 5/2)
     = (n - n ⋅ (5/2) ⋅ 5log₂(n) / 2log₂(n)) / (1 - 5/2)
     = (n - n ⋅ (5/2) ⋅ 5log₂(n) / n) / (1 - 5/2)
     = (n - (5/2) ⋅ 5log₂(n)) / (1 - 5/2)
     = ((5/2) ⋅ 5log₂(n) - n) / (5/2 - 1)
     = ((5/2) ⋅ 5log₂(n) - n) / (3/2)
     = (5/3) ⋅ 5log₂(n) - (2/3) ⋅ n             ∈ Θ(5log₂(n))
```

Now you only have to show `5log₂(n) = nlog₂(5)`, which can be done in about one line.

The recurrence equation, I get for Chris, is

```
T(n) = 2⋅T(n-1) + O(1)
```

This is not solvable by using the master theorem, but you can just expand it to a sum and solve it:

```
T(n) = 2⋅T(n-1) + Θ(1)
     = 2⋅(2⋅T(n-2)+ Θ(1)) + Θ(1)
     = 2²⋅T(n-2) + 2⋅Θ(1) + Θ(1)
     ...
     = 2n⋅T(1) + 2n-1⋅Θ(1) + ... + 2⋅Θ(1) + Θ(1)
     = 2n+1⋅Θ(1) - 1         ∈ Θ(2n)
```

This holds for `T(1) ∈ Θ(1)`.